# using multiple tables and conditioning tds

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using datatables table plugin and I'm using it globally across my site so that I can have all my tables use the same settings. What I'm wanting to do is have it set up to where it it comes across one of the th's that have a certain id then it takes off the sorting and adjust the size of the column but not sure how I can do that if the td has a certain id.

```
$(window).load(function(){
var oTable = $('.dataTable').dataTable({
} );

$('.selectall').toggle(
    function() {
        $(this).closest('.table').find('.messages').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).prop('checked', true)
    },
    function() {
        $(this).closest('.table').find('.messages').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).prop('checked', false)
    }
);
});
```

Comment: I'm wondering if anyone has ever done that before, because it'd be nice to be able to do this. Reason being I'm using the same datatables created code globally and on my tables say I have a id field as the one first column but might have it on the second column on a different table.

Comment: I don't have any special options YET that's why I'm wanting to know how it could be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just make a js script page that has all the different code for each table in there and save that.